# Looping through arrays in asp.net is not working

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net

I have an array which sometimes holds values like `"ABC, XYZ, TTT"` and sometime only `"ABC"`
So while iterating through the arrays when it holds multiple it checks only for the first item and not the other item.

```
string[] strStateArray = new string[] { "" };
                    strStateArray = strOne.Split(',');

 for (int i = 0; i < strStateArray.Length; i++)
                    {                            
                        if (dt.Rows[0]["CIRCLE"].ToString() == strStateArray[i].ToString()) // not checking for multiple items
                        {
            }
        }
```

**updated code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < strStateArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[0]["CIRCLE"].ToString() == strStateArray[i].Trim().ToString())
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                dt.TableName = "RecodSet";
                                string xml = ConvertDatatableToXML(dt);
                                mycon.Close();

                                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), key, "alert('File uploaded successfully.!!');", true);
                                //  System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('File uploaded successfully.!!');", true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string noData = "No data to upload.";
                                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", noData, false);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string file_name = fluUploadBtn.FileName;

                            if ((System.IO.File.Exists(file_name)))
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Delete(file_name);
                            }
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), key, "alert('User is not authorised to upload data for state mentioned in excel report ');", true);
                        }                            
                    }
```

Comment: you are checking CIRCLE value of only first row from data table against the value in the array, is this intended?

Comment: What's the expected behavior and what actual behavior? Can you share some more details with example data both in array and datatable?

Comment: @Chetan: No, I want to check all the array values i.e `strStateArray[i]` against CIRCLE

Comment: `it checks only for the first item and not the other item.` how do you confirm this?

Comment: ok , I have `CIRCLE = 'Haryana'` and in array the values are stored as `'Delhi,Maharashtra,Haryana'` so I want to check against all the 3 values and if one is true then go inside the loop else out

Comment: I guess there's an issue with whitespaces. ' XYZ'. Please remove it with: strStateArray[i].Trim().ToString())

Comment: @MarkusMeyer: that is not the actual mate. its just for question purpose. WHat actual issue is I am not able to iterate for all the values in the array

Comment: @Chetan: its confirmed because it directly goes in else condition after the first condition doesn't matches it.. it does not check the second values in arrays

Comment: your code is working on my machine. The iteration is working. Only the if statement is always false because of the whitespace https://imgur.com/JxCMi6E

Comment: how about the other vlaues in the array? if the first item does not match it will go in else part then next item will be compared... that is not happening? does it get out of the loop in else block? can oyu share the entire code of for loop?

Comment: let me check with trim

Comment: Looking at the code... there is no way that it will get out of the for loop just after comparing the first item in the array. Either there is an error of something big I am missing..

Comment: I just got it. if it first goes in ELSE, then it prompts the error msg in alert. so even if it checks second and third time, the user thinks the file has not been uploaded. SO how can I make it working if it checks for first time in else and another two times in IF.

Comment: You might want to rethink the logic.... instead of showing multiple alerts you might want to combine all the errors and show them as one alert or as validation error. I am not sure why you have `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` block, you don't need   that because if `dt.Rows.Count` is zero it `dt.Rows[0]` in the line above would have thrown the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just go debug the value then?

let me rewrite some code for you

```
String logMsg ="";
String targetKeyword = dt.Rows[0]["CIRCLE"].ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < strStateArray.Length; i++)
{
       String tmp_Val_Pure = strStateArray[i] ==null? null : strStateArray[i].ToString();   //debug here see the value1
       String tmp_Val = strStateArray[i] ==null? "" : strStateArray[i].ToString().Trim(); //debug here see the value2
       bool isThisOk =  (targetKeyword == tmp_Val );   //debug here see the val of isThisOk 
      if ( isThisOk  )
      {
          logMsg += "Success Record : "+ i.ToString() + " val : " + tmp_Val ; 
           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {  // alert case OK
            } else { // alert no val dt  }
      }
      else
      {  
          logMsg += "Err Record : "+ i.ToString() + " val : " + tmp_Val ;           
      }
} //end loop
//Go check logMsg
```